# ¿Por que Visual Studio me muestra el codigo sin colores?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues bien, estoy usando Visual Studio 2010 (me pasa lo mismo en la version 2013), y a la hora de agregar un script en visual basic me lo muestra así, sin colores, como si fuera texto plano. Eso no seria problema si no fuera por que tampoco me deja agregar puntos de interrupción y me cuesta un poco mas de trabajo analizar el código así, a alguien le ha sucedido lo mismo??

Comment: que tipo de archivo le dijiste que era?

Comment: .aspx
Y el codigo mostrado es un script en VB